# How to combine date with time, typed by hand in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have date: '2015-01-01' and time: '15:01:45'

How to make it '2015-01-01 15:01:45' ?

This is my failed attempt:

```
SELECT CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE) + CAST('10:21:38' AS TIME)
```

I get an error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.

Comment: Why not simply concatenate the strings? `x + ' ' + y` ? The question is a bit ambiguous, do you want the result to be a `DateTime` or a text?

Comment: ok thx it works, I just had to first determin 111545 as time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT cast(my_date + ' ' + my_time as datetime)
```

Comment: now how do this if I have '2015-01-01' in one column and '10:21:38' in another? if I do: select cast(my_date + my_time as datetime) from ##x2 then time is added to year as year :(

Comment: Given that the default date format on the server is the one used to create the string and the strings are always valid dates and times.

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @faryzeusz You have to also add a space between the two fields, like `cast(my_date + ' ' + my_time as datetime) from ##x2`. This way the string is converted into a `datetime` value.

Comment: You should clean the data *prior* to storing it in the database!

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you can concatenate the variable with space in between and CAST as datetime

```
DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR (50) = '2015-01-01';
DECLARE @Time AS VARCHAR (50) = '10:21:38'
SELECT CAST(@Date + ' ' + @Time AS DATETIME) AS Result FROM ##x2
```

Comment: and how to this when in one column I got '2015-01-01' which is date format, and in the another i got 111545  which should be 11:15:45 ?

Comment: @faryzeusz we can't help to clean your data. If the storage format is ambigous, you can not extract the data. Period. You can't tell if 12/11/10 is the 10th of november in 2012, or 11th of october in 2012 or 11th of december in 2010.